# ImageView dynamic xml drawable

Tags: android, imageview, xml-drawable

I have an ImageView that has the following drawable set:

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/default_image_round" />
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="13dp">
            <corners
                android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
                android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
                android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
                android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and I want to change the android:drawable from the above xml to other image.

I try:

```
Picasso.with(mContext).load(f).resize(mNewCarRound.getWidth(),mNewCarRound.getHeight()).centerCrop().into(mNewCarRound);
```

but it override the above xml and put my picture

Is there a way to be able to set an id on

Comment: remove the src attribute from your imageView and both images dynamically then it works perfect.